# Mongodb : Search for entries having one to many mapping between 2 fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database, containing entities of ECommerceProducts. There are two fields, "productId" and "skuId". The thing is many of the records are duplicated, i.e., it is possible that two entries have same "productId" as well as same "skuId".

I want to find the set of productIds that have multiple (distinct) skuIds present.

This is what I have till now:

```
db.urls.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { productId: "$productId" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gte: 2 } 
  } },
  { $sort : { count : -1} },
  { $limit : 10 }
]);
```

This code gives me the list of Duplicate productIds and how many times they have occurred. How can I also get the list of different skuIds these contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) accumulator

```
db.urls.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { productId: "$productId" },
    skuId: {$addToSet: "$skuId"},
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gte: 2 } 
  } },
  { $sort : { count : -1} },
  { $limit : 10 }
]);
```

This will return all product IDs that appear more than once with a distinct set of all skuId used by them.

Comment: This worked like a charm. How can I get the number of such entries?